# How to rename Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have created a topic and I'm not using it, but now I want to use it for another application. so instead of creating new one I want to rename and use it. is it possible?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KAFKA-2333

Answer (score 26):

In straight and simple there is no concept of renaming topics in kafka

Comment: I really like such when such "it's just not possible" answers get upvotes and accepts!

Answer (score 8):

Renaming a topic is not a supported operation.  However, the latest Kafka versions now support topic deletion.  So you can simply delete the old topic, and create a new one with the new name.

If you had data you want to save, you can also use `mirrormaker` to copy data from the old topic to the new one.

Comment: how to backup the old topic offsets at the same time

Comment: Indeed, copying events from one topic to another without keeping track of offsets won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Renaming a Kafka topic is not a supported operation. Might I ask why the existing name would be unsuitable for another application?